# Download Git Zipball in Unix

Tags: wget, github

I'm trying to download a zipball of a git repo:

e.g.

```
wget https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/zipball/master
```

This works fine in a web browser but on unix the file gets a weird name...how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say weird name, what do you mean?

This should however just be a ZIP-file. It just doesn't have the extension.

You can check this with the following command:

```
file master
```

You can unzip it with this command:

```
unzip master
```

Comment: master isnt the name of the final zipfile, its a redirect.

Comment: I know, but I don't know what it's going to be, so I use `master` here. Nonetheless, it'll be a ZIP-file.

Answer (score 1):

You also get a 'weird name' in your web browser, the server is redirecting you from

https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/zipball/master

to somewhere on nodeload.github.com, are you saying that wget isnt following these redirects? Can you paste the output, and show the results of wget, with an ls -l.

If you want to make sure that the downloaded file has another name, use the `-O` option.

```
wget -O myzip.zip https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/zipball/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
git archive --remote=git://git.foo.com/project.git HEAD:path/to/directory filename
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository